# click a button with javascript which has same name as another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to code an autoclicker in a Chrome extension using Javascript, however with a special type a button.

Here are 2 examples of the button:

```html
<button ng-bind-html="option.value" type="button" tabindex="15" ng-click="optionClickHandler(option)" ng-disabled="formFieldModel.disabled || isOptionDisabled(option) || showSpinner" ng-class="{ 'selected': option &amp;&amp; formFieldModel &amp;&amp; option.id === formFieldModel.eventExtraFieldValueId, 'disabled': isOptionDisabled(option) }" class="ng-binding selected">The App</button>
```

and

```html
<button ng-bind-html="option.value" type="button" tabindex="15" ng-click="optionClickHandler(option)" ng-disabled="formFieldModel.disabled || isOptionDisabled(option) || showSpinner" ng-class="{ 'selected': option &amp;&amp; formFieldModel &amp;&amp; option.id === formFieldModel.eventExtraFieldValueId, 'disabled': isOptionDisabled(option) }" class="ng-binding">NTC App</button>
```

How can I click one of them when both are displayed on the page? Thank you.

Comment: Find a difference between the elements and select the specific button you want by that. For example their text, or a parent element which is unique. There's not really enough useful information in the question to offer any further assistance

Comment: document.querySelector('[ng-bind-html="option.value"]').click() How do i specify the text in the button in that command?

Comment: If they're always in the same order you could essentially do `$("button").eq(1).click()` to click the second - add other attributes, even if they're the same to limit down to the 2 buttons

Comment: thank you for your answer, however if i want to specify a specific button because of the string displayed?

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery

```
$('button:contains("The App")').click()
```

Otherwise

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'))
  .filter(s => s.innerText === "The App")
  .forEach(s => s.click())
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, when i do document.getallelementbyTagName('button') all buttons are displayed this way : button.ng-binding, button.ng-binding, button.ng-binding, button.ng-binding, button.ng-binding, button.ng-binding, button.ng-binding, button.ng-binding, so that is why it does not click

Comment: @Mehditation please see my edited answer above using document.querySelectorAll

Comment: *If you use jQuery* - and if you *don't* use jquery, then don't tag your question with [tag:jquery]...

Comment: thank you it still doesn't work, try it on this webpage (https://www.nike.com/events-registration/event?id=1618516799261) but change string to "Twitter", it does not work for me.

Comment: @Mehditation It worked, I tested with jQuery version, however the Twitter button is hidden in the `<div ng-show="userData.loggedIn" class="ng-hide">` parent not visible to you.

Comment: $('button:contains("Twitter")').click() gets me nothing, sorry im no trying to waste your time, i just don't get it, and if i want to use query how do i do it?

Comment: it does not make sens, i know where is the key word located but it does do nothing on that button for me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the only difference between the buttons is the class.
You can select a button with the specific class like this:

```
$("button.ng-binding")
```

Comment: sorry it is because the button was selected  my mistake!

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but note that both the button elements have this class.